# Arrangements in a circle such that A is closer to F than B is to F

Tags: combinatorics

There are six things labelled $A$ to $F$. I need to calculate the number of distinct circular arrangements such that $A$ is closer to $F$ than $B$ is.

Here's what makes sense to me: fix $F$. Either $A$ is closer, further, or equidistant (than/with $B$). By symmetry the probabilities of 'closer' and 'further' are equal, say $p$. Let the probability of 'equidistant' be $q$. Then $1=q+2p$. Upon fixing $F$ there are four arrangements in which $A,B$ are equidistant, so $q=\frac 4{5!}$. Hence $p=\frac 12(1-\frac 4{5!})$, and $5!\cdot p=58$ which is my answer.

Is this okay? If not, what are my mistakes?

Comment: Just to be sure, do you mean to say "such that A is closer to F than B is to F" or "such that A is closer to F than A is to B"? Either interpretation seems possible. Note that this does not change the actual question, but it does change interpretation of your attempt to solve the question.

Comment: "There are four arrangements in which A, B are equidistant from F" implies the AF/BF formulation.

Comment: @HSN I meant closer to or further than $F$.

Comment: Check my edit: Is this what you mean?

Comment: @Lovsovs $1=q+2p$ was put into the question. Hence it should be "closer" only, not "closer or farther" (which would be $1=q+p$).

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Hmm, then how do you interpret OPs latest comment?

Comment: May have flip-flopped on the matter. First it was said "only closer", and the equations backed that up, but then may have realised a mistake was made.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Then I will leave my edit as is for know (and pray that OP shouts out if s/he wants it corrected).

Comment: @Lovsovs, sorry, I'm a bit confused myself now. I'm just asking about the cases in which the distance from $A$ to $F$ is smaller than the distance of $B$ to $F$.

Answer (score 1):

The number of ways to choose the positions for A and B is $5\cdot4=20$,

so this gives $p=\frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{4}{20})=\frac{2}{5}$.

---

Alternate solution:

1) If A is one place away from F, then there are 2 choices for A and 3 choices for B.

2) If A is two places away from F, then there are 2 choices for A and only 1 choice for B.

Therefore $ p=\frac{2\cdot3+2\cdot1}{5\cdot4}=\frac{8}{20}=\frac{2}{5}$.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, but you calculated the number of arrangements in which $A$ and $B$ are equidistant from $F$ incorrectly. There are indeed $4$ placements of $A$ and $B$, but for each of them there are $3!$ ways to fill the $3$ positions not occupied by $A,B$, or $F$ with $C,D$, and $E$. Thus, there are actually $4\cdot3!$ arrangements in which $A$ and $B$ are equidistant from $F$, and

$$p=\frac12\left(1-\frac{4\cdot3!}{5!}\right)=\frac25\;.$$

You can keep the numbers smaller by adopting **user84413**’s approach and looking only at the $20$ possible locations for $A$ and $B$ instead of at the $5!$ possible arrangements of $A,B,C,D$, and $E$: no matter where $A$ and $B$ are, there are $3!$ possible arrangements of $D,E$, and $F$.